# MongoTemplate - get the connection URI

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

We are injecting the mongotemplate using the spring config

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" connection-string="${mongodb.connect-string}">
   <mongo:client-settings read-preference="PRIMARY_PREFERRED" retry-writes="true" />
</mongo:mongo-client>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongodb.database}" mongo-client-ref="mongoClient" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
   <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>
```

```
@Inject
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Now we are creating a separate integration checkpoint to ensure the mongo db is available and show a green or red traffic light. Is it possible to get the connection URI from the instantiated mongotemplate or I should use ${mongodb.connect-string} to build the integration point?

In the older version of mongotemplate (springDataMongoDb : 1.8.2) we were able to use the following method to get the address

```
ServerAddress address = mongoTemplate.getDb().getMongo().getAddress();
```

but with spring 3.4.6 it is not possible to get the address using the above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ${mongodb.connect-string} as you suggested since this is much more straight forward and doesn't require you to have to wire in the mongo template just to return a constant value when that is the exact propose of spring configs via the @Value annotation.

But a better solution to the green/red for mongo connectivity is using spring actuator which already has this functionality built in.

https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-health-check/